# how do i verify if rails is installed correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Michael Hartl's rails tutorial to learn rails; I am a beginner.I am in the process of setting up the IDE. I am not 100% sure if I have installed rails and ruby gems correctly.

Can anyone suggest how to verify this before I move on to trying the actual coding? I believe git and ruby v2 are installed ok based on typing in `git -v` and `ruby -v`

However, when I type in `rails --version`, I get a  message that differs from what's in the tutorial. I can pm a printscreen of what I'm seeing; help would be appreciated as I do not want to give up.

Comment: i have been trying to use rails installer for windows and the webchat help they have (irc)...but i would appreciate anybody who is willing to help as i have spent a lot of time trying to figure this out unsuccessfully. i feel the end justifies the mean (i.e. if i can get it done its more important than learning all the details as i have a fulltime job and may not be able to be a great programmer in the near term but would like to spend time coding and just asking quetsions as a better way of learning given the broad scope of comp sci and development)

Comment: Rails development on windows is very hard, you may be able to install plain rails, but some of the prominent libraries will not build, or take a lot of effort for it to work. I would recommend installing VMware or the like and install a Linux Distro, and work from there, trust me, in the long run it will save time. The only reason I use Mac at work is it is so simple to program ruby. Linux will do as well, just can't find IDE's and versioning software that feels right.

Comment: What's the error message you are getting when you run `rails --version` ?

Comment: its not an error per se...i will transcribe it now...i can't copy and paste from the cmd window

Comment: there is a new line after each 'from'...sorry if that's tough to follow...the whole thing is the error message or whatever it is...thanks for any assistance...

Comment: The relevant error message is `Could not find minitest <~> 4.2` at the very top of the stack trace. Make sure you have run `bundle install` as explained at the end of http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial?version=4.0#sec-bundler

Comment: In terms of the Hart'l tutorial I have installed ruby, rails, and git...I just need to get the gems and I'm good to go

Comment: Cool. Follow Hartl's tutorial very closely, and review the pages a few times when you get stuck. Feel free to start over again as it doesn't take too much time, and will help you internalize the concepts better. As a beginner, it is really difficult to get a grasp of all the concepts at the first read.

Comment: wow i think i got it!! gems are now installed

Comment: Prakash - I had a question - For 1.2.4 Bundler - I don't understand the "subl Gemfile" command. Do I need to use Sublime Text (text editor). I also downloaded Aptana IDE befoer that but didn't know how to use it. The command doesn't seem to work in the command prompt